# InvalidArgumentError: indices[127,7] = 43 is not in [0, 43) in Keras R

Tags: r, indexing, keras, tokenize

The issue is related 
 to: [InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[1] = 10 is not in [0, 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567398/invalidargumenterror-see-above-for-traceback-indices1-10-is-not-in-0-10/52310338#52310338)
I need it for R and therefore another solution than given in the link above.

```
maxlen <- 40
chars <- c("'",  "-",  " ",  "!",  "\"", "(",  ")",  ",",  ".",  ":",  ";",  "?",  "[",  "]",  "_",  "=",  "0", "a",  "b",  "c",  "d",  "e", "f",  "g",  "h",  "i",  "j",  "k",  "l",  "m",  "n",  "o",  "p",  "q",  "r",  "s",  "t",  "u",  "v",  "w",  "x",  "y",  "z")



tokenizer <- text_tokenizer(char_level = T, filters = NULL)

tokenizer %>% fit_text_tokenizer(chars)
unlist(tokenizer$word_index)
```

Output is:

```
 '  -     !  "  (  )  ,  .  :  ;  ?  [  ]  _  =  0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
```

How can I change the indexing so it starts from 0 not from 1 in text_tokenizer?

The error I get after running fit() is as follows:

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[127,7] = 43 is not in [0, 43)
     [[Node: embedding_3/embedding_lookup = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_1/RMSprop/Assign_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_3/embeddings/read, embedding_3/Cast, training_1/RMSprop/gradients/embedding_3/embedding_lookup_grad/concat/axis)]]
```

But I believe that changing the Indexing will solve my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Index 0 is often reserved for **padding** so it is not a wise idea to start your actual character indices from 0 as well. Instead you should venture to the `Embedding` layer and add 1 to the input size as suggested by the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/):

> **input_dim:** int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.

In your case this would be 43 + 1 = 44.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `Embedding` layer with vocabulary size. For example:

```
model.add(Embedding(875, 64))
```

In this case, 875 is the length of my vocabulary.